# matlab: lsqcurvefit and parameters

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, optional-parameters

I'm trying to do some fitting with lsqcurvefit. I have a function like that:

```
function F = cdf_3p_model(a,data)
F=1-((1-a(5)-a(6)).*(exp(-abs(data)./a(1)))+((1-a(4)-a(6)).*(exp(-abs(data)./a(2))))+((1-a(4)-a(5)).*(exp(-abs(data)./a(3)))));
```

and

```
function [a residual] = cdf_fit_3p(x,y)
a0 = [10 1 0.1 0.3 0.3 0.3];
lb = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
ub = [];
curvefitoptions = optimset('Display','final','MaxFunEvals',100000,'MaxIter',50000);
[a, residual] = fmincon(@cdf_3p_model,a0,x,y,lb,ub,curvefitoptions);
end
```

I set the initial parameters, ub, lb but how do I also declare that:

```
a(1) > a(2) > a(3)
a(5) + a(6) +a(7) = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have better chance using one of the minimization routines such as [fmincon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fmincon.html) which allows you to specify constraints you might otherwise be unable to do. You can easily incorporate least-squares by taking the L2-norm of the difference between model and data

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It sounds quite easy, but I've just started with matlab and to be honest have no idea how to " incorporate least-squares by taking the L2-norm of the difference between model and data" :) could you please give some more hints?

Comment: maybe I was too technical. Say your data's real values is found in `F` in vector format, and the model approximation via fitting is `Fm`. The purpose of least squares is to minimize the distance (specifically "euclidean") between F and Fm. See [Euclidean norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_norm#Euclidean_norm) courtesy of wikipedia. So ultimately if you return the norm to fmincon, it will try to minimize it, thus performing your LS-approximation

Comment: as an extra hint regarding the constraints: function [c,ceq] = curvefitoptions(x). Set `c = [x(2) -x(1); x(3) - x(2)]` and `ceq = x(5) + x(6) +x(7) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would say, "make clauses in your function that gives really terrible 'scores' when those conditions are not met."  However, your conditions make the range of allowable parameters such a tiny, tiny subset of the range of possible numbers that I think you would cause lsqcurvefit to never converge if you do that.  I would say lsqcurvefit is not the right solution for you.

Comment: thanks for your opinion. So, what might be the better solution for me (who is not very fluid on math and matlab)?  :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to calculate the parameters you "want" from a set of parameters that's more usable to MatLab.

For example, you can rewrite

```
a(1) > a(2) > a(3)
a(5) + a(6) + a(7) = 1
```

as

```
a(3) = p(1)
a(2) = p(1) + p(2)
a(1) = p(1) + p(2) + p(3)
a(4) = p(4)
a(5) = p(5)
a(6) = p(6)
a(7) = 1 - p(5) - p(6)
```

with

```
lb = [0 0 0 0 0 0]
ub = [Inf Inf Inf Inf 1 1]
```

Well, it's not perfect, because it allows a(7) as low as -1 instead of 0.  But it includes your other constraints.